# Keycloak (bitnami) in EKS :: Trying to connect to PostgreSQL server keycloak-postgresql... timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"

Tags: postgresql, keycloak, amazon-eks

I tried to deploy keycloak (bitnami) via helmcheck and ArgoCD ... everything starts fine except of the postgres

```
keycloak 10:02:13.82 INFO ==>
keycloak 10:02:13.82 INFO ==> Welcome to the Bitnami keycloak container
keycloak 10:02:13.82 INFO ==> Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
keycloak 10:02:13.82 INFO ==> Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
keycloak 10:02:13.83 INFO ==>
keycloak 10:02:13.83 INFO ==> ** Starting keycloak setup **
keycloak 10:02:13.84 INFO ==> Validating settings in KEYCLOAK_* env vars...
keycloak 10:02:13.86 INFO ==> Trying to connect to PostgreSQL server keycloak-postgresql...
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"
keycloak 10:04:43.91 ERROR ==> Unable to connect to host keycloak-postgresql
```

any idea what's wrong? I have pretty much the default settings except the ingress (mapped to the respective domain name -> when used -> it gives me 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable)